# Segmented Control tintColor not setting correctly when used with if/else clause

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a `UISegmentedController`. When its value changes, this code is executed:

```
    println(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)

        var x = 0

        if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
        {
            println("set to \(self.yellow)")
            sender.tintColor = self.yellow
            println("right after \(sender.tintColor)")
            x = 1
        }
        else if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
        {
            println("set to \(self.green)")
            sender.tintColor == self.green
            println("right after \(sender.tintColor)")
            x = 2
        }
        else if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
        {
            println("set to \(self.blue)")
            sender.tintColor == self.blue
            println("right after \(sender.tintColor)")
            x = 3
        }

    println("what it actually got set to: \(sender.tintColor), x is \(x)")
```

Here is the output when I tap each segment in succession:

```
0
set to UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0.83 0.13 1
right after UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0.83 0.13 1
what it actually got set to: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0.83 0.13 1, x is 1
1
set to UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.38 0.85 0.38 1
right after UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0.83 0.13 1
what it actually got set to: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0.83 0.13 1, x is 2
2
set to UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.34 0.73 0.85 1
right after UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0.83 0.13 1
what it actually got set to: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0.83 0.13 1, x is 3
```

You can see that reading the tintColor right after setting shows the wrong value for `selectedSegmentIndex` of 1 and 2.

If I convert the entire if/else into a switch() statement, it works as expected.

One other data point, if I set the `backgroundColor` to a different color in each of the if clauses, the backgrounds change accordingly but the `tintColor` doesn't change as described above.

This is running in the release version of Xcode 6.0.1. What's going on?

Comment: Is it just returning the wrong value or does it also *look* wrong afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing for equality, not assigning it. You should only be using a single equal sign:

```
sender.tintColor = self.green
```

My guess is that you were not making the same mistake when you had it implemented as a switch

Comment: Good catch! Damn ObjC. Welcome Swift :)

Comment: Wow. What a rookie mistake. I blame late night coding. Thanks!